# How to check whether (alt + tab ) is pressed using javascript and how to 1) disable it 2)how to close current browser

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether (alt + tab) is pressed or not if pressed then I want (1) how to close present browser
2) how to disable (alt+tab)

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't detect that it's been pressed,¹ and you can't cancel it — nor should you be able to. The user's workstation is *theirs*, not yours. Separately, it's mostly pointless (for instance, to prevent cheating during an online exam) in this age of people with multiple internet-connected devices.

Administering remote tests is a hard problem that I suspect hasn't been solved yet. It will not be solved by trying to lock users into the browser.

---

¹ A quick test using the `keydown` event, for instance, didn't even fire the event on my workstation. Alt+Tab to switch between applications is handled at a lower level than the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, there are some examples:

1. You can create a desktop app using something like electron 
   Solution: [Disable keyboard shortcuts Alt + Tab in electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138838/disable-keyboard-shortcuts-alt-tab-in-electron-application)
2. Check out Page Visibility API (probably it's what you want to achieve) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API