# What is Electron's 'kiosk' mode?

Tags: electron, kiosk

What exactly does `kiosk: true` in the `BrowserWindow` config of a new ElectronJS window do?

The [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/api/browser-window#winkiosk) just states that the parameter indicates, that the window is in 'kiosk' mode. I was unable to find information on what this means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, Kiosk mode is a Windows operating system (OS) feature that only allows one application to run. Kiosk mode is a common way to lock down a Windows device when that device is used for a specific task or used in a public setting.

So in electron kiosk mode, we'd have the ability to lock down our application to a point that users are restricted to the actions that we want them to perform. Also, the browser would merely act as our canvas with exactly defined capabilities and doesn't get into our way. And this is why you want to use Electron!

Answer (score 3):

It's true that this feature is not very well documented. There is a open bug about it : [Kiosk mode is poorly documented](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31860)

This seems that the kiosk flags brings some like :

- Disable the F11 key to exit full screen
- Disable keyboard shortcuts for navigating or creating new tabs / windows
- Prevents other programs from popping up on your screen

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@andreas.schallwig/building-html5-kiosk-applications-with-vue-js-and-electron-c64ac928b59f), but I was unable to replicate all behaviours.

I think that under the hood it's may be linked to the `kiosk` command line switch in chromium : [--kiosk](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#kiosk).